# Reading a Ruby generated YAML file with YamlDotNet

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, ruby, yamldotnet

I run into 2 issue reading a Ruby Yaml file with the YamlDotNet.RepresentationModel. The file

```
en:
  duplicateid:
      one: ONE
      two: TWO
      three: THREE
      two: TWOTWO
      four: FOUR
  plurals:
      files:
        one: 1 file
        other: ! '%{count} files'
      minutes:
        one: 1 minute
        other: ! '%{count} minutes'
```

when tested with yamllint.com (which seems to be optimized for Ruby) is valid. When checking the duplicate id is deleted as well as the exclamation mark from the non-specific tag.

YamlDotNet gives an error, first for the duplicate id, and when deleting it for the non-specific tag (While parsing a tag, did not find expected tag URI.)

Any ideas on how to solve boths problems?

Thanks for any feedback

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Ruby Yaml file", there are only YAML files; YAML is a cross-language data format. Ruby's YAML parser/serializer emits YAML spec compliant files. If you give it custom objects it'll try to serialize them as custom objects, which is what the `!` means if I remember right, but you'll run into trouble with other languages trying to read them. Who is generating that YAML?

Comment: Why do you have/need a duplicated ID in your YML. Technically, this isn't valid YML with duplicate keys so you should fix that problem first.